# LoRa Ra-01 P2P distance

Tags: lora

I am using LoRa RA-01 to P2P communication. I set the parameter of module to default value but max distance (range) that it is obtained less 5 meters.

My project algorithm is :

Transmitter side :
1_Enable LoRa modem.
2_Select STDBY mode.
3_Mapping TxDone interrupt on DIO0 pin.
4_Upload RegFifoTxBaseAdd content(0x80) to buffer pointer.
5_Write 0x60 value(a typical value) to buffer.
6_Write 0x01 to RegPayloadLength register.
7_When switch closed(switch is connect to host uc)Select Tx mode repeatedly(with 1 second delay) for send data continually.
8_500 mili second after switch opened the interrupt flag is cleared.

Receiver side :
1_Enable LoRa modem.
2_Select STDBY mode.
3_Mapping RxDone interrupt on DIO0 pin(default).
4_Select Receive continuous mode.
5_When switch closed the interrupt flag is cleared.

Note 1 : I use antenna that is presented with module.
Note 2 : This project is only for testing range.
Note 3 : I need a distance about 400 meters indoor.

Question 1 : Is this module work without antenna in range about hundreds meters?
Question 2 : How do i configure these module for high distance(less 1 kilometer)(with or without antenna)?

I apology for i don't speak English fluently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved.The default value of registers is bad value for long distance.I left registers value to default value due i did not wanted using a library,but now i is forced to using a library.